# Geometric translation of a theorem about stability of equilibrium point

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems

In the book Nonlinear Systems by Hassan Khalil, there is a theorem about the stability of equilibrium point ‎ which asserts that :

**Theorem :**‎
Let‎
‎$X=0$ ‎be an equilibrium point for‎
‎$‎\dot x = f(x)‎$‎
where‎
‎$f : D ‎\rightarrow ‎R^n‎$‎ is a locally Lipschitz map from a domain‎
‎$D \subset R^n$‎ into ‎
‎$R^n$‎‎ and‎
‎$D $
containing‎
‎$x = 0 $‎ . Let‎
‎$V : D ‎\rightarrow R ‎‎‎$‎ be a continuously differentiable function, such
that
‎$‎V(0) = 0‎$‎ and ‎$‎V(x) \gt 0‎$‎ in ‎$‎D - ‎\lbrace0\rbrace‎‎‎‎$‎ 
‎$‎‎\dot V(x) ‎\leq ‎0‎‎$‎ in ‎$‎D‎$‎ .
Then ‎$‎x = 0‎$‎ is stable. Moreover, if
‎$‎‎\dot V(x) \lt 0‎$‎ in ‎$‎D - ‎\lbrace0‎\rbrace‎‎$ then $‎x = 0‎$‎ is asymptotically stable.

‎
My question is that what is the geometric representation (i.e. geometric translation or visualization) of the function ‎$V$ ‎in ‎this ‎theorem.‎
Thanks in advance for any forthcoming idea/comment.

Answer (score 1):

V shall be the energy of your system.

Comment: I can't see how. Would you mind explain it more?

Comment: For example in the case of a pendulum, we have $\ddot{\theta}=-sin(\theta)$. $0$ is an equilibrium since $f(0)=0$ (here, $f(\theta, \dot{\theta})=(\dot{\theta},-sin{\theta}))$. V can be for example $(1-cos{\theta})+\frac{1}{2}\dot{\theta}^2$ : the energy is a function that fills the hypothesis of the theorem.

Comment: Now if all you're interested in is the mathematical aspect, V has no general geometric representation as if such a function exists, then there is a infinite set of other functions V that are suitable too.

Answer (score 1):

The $V$ function, also known as a [Lyapunov function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Lyapunov.27s_second_method_for_stability), can be considered as a function approximation to the true potential function of the system, which usually means energy. Or, to put it another way, $V$ doesn't represent the energy of a system, but a function that approximates it.

To determine a $V$ function, we consider *Lyapunov function candidates* which need to satisfy at least $V\ge0$ and $\dot V\le0$, and usually we hope to bound the actual potential function, $P_V$ say from above, i.e. $|P_V(x)|\le|V(x)|,\;\forall x\in D$. This allows for a reasonable determination of the behaviour of a system.

A Lyapunov function has *Lyapunov surfaces* given by $V_c=\{x|V(x)=c\}$ which show in a geometric sense the 'potential' of $V$ (chapter $3$, page $102$ of 'Nonlinear Systems - Hassan Khalil') as contours on a relief map.